# How to make image swallowed out of window size without create blank space

Tags: html, css

this is something I built:
https://i.imagesup.co/images2/e51854cad0f72ef2900debd5518472d71713cc71.png
There is no overflow because I put in body tag overflow-x:hidden, and it's kind of "nasty" way.

I tried to set div container as width:100vw,max-width:100vw; but it's still not helping. tried to do it with a negative margin and every possible way I know but it's still create overflow like this:
https://i.imagesup.co/images2/794cf0f60d80b8a2de4f5ac44d93579bd50ace2d.png

This the relevant code of the light blue part, thanks in advance:

```
<body>
    <div id="divStyle1">
        <header>
            <h1>
                <span>How to <span class="importantH1">ripen Avocado</span> quickly ?</span>
                <span><span class="importantH1">RFP bags</span> ripen Avocado within <span class="importantH1">12-24 hours !</span></span>
            </h1>
        </header>

        <main>            
            <div id="purpuleLineBox">
                <div id="purpuleLine1"> <p>100% recyclable and bio-degradable</p> </div>
                <div id="purpuleLine2"> <p>Simulates the natural ripening process, organic</p> </div>
                <div id="purpuleLine3"> <p>The quickest way to achieve the  perfect avocado taste</p> </div>
                <div id="purpuleLine4"> <p>Work with Mango, Banana, Peach, and another climacteric fruits</p> </div>
                <div id="purpuleLine5"> <p>The user interface on the bag shows when an avocado is fully ripen</p> </div>
            </div>

            <img id="logoImg" src="Logo.png" alt="">
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#divStyle1 {
    height: 90vh;
    background-color: #016087;
}

h1>span {
    display: block;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    font-size: 45px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.importantH1 {
    border-bottom: 10px solid #D52C82;
    font-size: 53px;
}

.importantH1:hover {
    border-bottom: 15px solid #D52C82;
    font-size: 55px;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

#logoImg {
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    top: 10vh;
    transform: rotate(8deg);
    border: 20px dashed white;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#purpuleLineBox {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#purpuleLine1 {
    background-color: #D52C82;
    height: 50px;
    width: 34%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#purpuleLine2 {
    background-color: #D52C82;
    height: 50px;
    width: 44%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#purpuleLine3 {
    background-color: #D52C82;
    height: 50px;
    width: 52%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#purpuleLine4 {
    background-color: #D52C82;
    height: 50px;
    width: 58%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#purpuleLine5 {
    background-color: #D52C82;
    height: 50px;
    width: 60%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

div>p {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Regarding overflow-x: hidden; what do you mean by "and it's kind of "nasty" way." does this break the layout?

Comment: it doesn't break the layout and it works really well, but the problem I don't understand what makes this happen. @CesarCorrechel

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to a combination of using absolutely positioned `right: -20px;` and `transform: rotate(8deg);` if you remove the transform and set right to 0 it should not have the blank space.

If you want to keep these styles just use `overflow-x: hidden;`

Comment: Yep, I know this. But this the only way to fix it?